# Is FLOP/s for a GPU constant with varied VRAM utilization?

Tags: processor, gpu

Meaning is the compute output of a GPU a function of total VRAM being used, or perhaps any other variable?

Comment: To change the amount of RAM utilized you would change what or how you are computing. If you change your computation, you might have higher or lower FLOPs. Essentially you're asking if all benchmarks give the same answer, which is not the case. But probably this is not really what you want to know.

Comment: @user1850479 Right. For example, given a GPU with sufficient memory for both tasks, how long would you expect each task to take if task 1 is multiplying 2 matrices of 1e6 floats and task 2 is multiplying 2 matrices of 1e7 floats. Does task 2 take 10x as long b/c its 10x the FLOPs or is there parallelization built in that makes the tasks finish equally fast/less than linear scaling.

Comment: Task 2 takes about 1000x longer since matrix multiplication scales with n^3.

Comment: @user1850479 Naïve matrix multiplication scales with n³, but [better algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm?useskin=vector) are known. The best known is about n^2.37, but isn't practical until you get to unimaginably large matrices. Strassen's algorithm, which is about O(n^2.8), is faster than naïve multiplication for matrices larger than about 100×100, which sounds reasonable to encounter in GPU calculations. (though I know little of graphics programming, so that could be wrong.)